# How to search double quotes in fulltext search in sql

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have double quotes in my Keyword. How can I search this in my fulltext search query. I have this query

```
SELECT  top 10 K.[KEY], 10, K.[RANK]
FROM    CONTAINSTABLE(ProductKeywords, Keywords, '("19*") AND ( "<Cat>5" OR "<Cat>30" OR "<Cat>398" ) AND NOT "<Blocked>"' ) AS k
```

It works fine but when i have double quotes in my keyword like

```
SELECT  top 10 K.[KEY], 10, K.[RANK]
FROM    CONTAINSTABLE(ProductKeywords, Keywords, '("19"*") AND ( "<Cat>5" OR "<Cat>30" OR "<Cat>398" ) AND NOT "<Blocked>"' ) AS k
```

it gives this error

```
Msg 7630, Level 15, State 3, Line 1
Syntax error near '*' in the full-text search condition '("19"*") AND ( "<Cat>5" OR "<Cat>30" OR "<Cat>398" ) AND NOT "<Blocked>"'.
```

Comment: you will find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886011/how-do-you-escape-double-quotes-inside-a-sql-fulltext-contains-function

Answer (score 1):

Since the content of 'Keywords' is interpreted by the RDBMS instead of being read literally, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection . This is also why you get the syntax errors.

You must sanitize the content of 'Keywords'. There's an answer on Stack Overflow : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102387/how-to-cleanse-dynamic-sql-in-sql-server-prevent-sql-injection).